# Which American-made science fiction or fantasy comic book was the first to be translated into a foreign language and marketed abroad?

Tags: comics, history-of

Which American-made science fiction or fantasy comic book was the first to be translated into a foreign language and marketed abroad? What language was it translated into, and what country was it intended for?

Comment: Are you asking about comic books like Famous Funnies, Action Comics, etc, or strips like Little Nemo and the like?

Comment: Specifically about comic books, but I found @Richard's answer enlightening.

Comment: If you're specifically after Action Comics, they were translated from about 1960 onwards; http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_large/11113/111139104/3516275-1.jpg

Comment: I would wonder if it might not be A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court, but can't find any translation history

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Kit Kelen's excellent "[The Nation in Children’s Literature: Nations of Childhood](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oYDTvISTdboC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=first%20american%20comic%20translated&source=bl&ots=v4aZdG4EVG&sig=eMb7IWVE7Uk9i16Z6cB6Yr9vkhA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yrwkU6qUO4yX0AXZnoHgBw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=first%20american%20comic%20translated&f=false)", the earliest Transatlantic translation was "Little Nemo" which was originally published in 1906 for the *New York Herald* and subsequently translated into Italian for the **1908** publication *Il Corrieri dei Piccoli* (Italian for "Courier of the Little Ones") a popular children's cartoon book.

[image: Little Nemo Herald]

[image: Little Nemo Piccoli]

Other American comics such as Happy Hooligan and Buster Brown entered the Italian market almost simultaneously the same year under the names Fortunello and Mimmo

Another American comic strip, “[Yellow Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Kid)” had previously been published in the Italian magazine *Il novellino* in **1904** but as a one-off set of pages rather than a regular serial.

Comment: I edited the question in an attempt for it not to be closed, so you might want to review it. I believe that Little Nemo in Slumberland counts as SFF based off [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3450/82909), because it's about fantastical dreams.